# PHP/MYSQL - Limit to last 500 then continue

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database

I have a script that adds tweets to a data base and another one the fetches those tweets and displays via php/ajax. This all works good with an empty db but if I already have a lot of tweets in there It runs intp problems. What I'm trying to do now is set the msql query to get the first say 500 rows and then continue on as tweets are added and ignore the preivous 500 tweets etc. So start at the latest row, get the latest row upto 500max then next time its queried get ro 1001, 1002, 1003 each.

Any ideas on how I could do this? Once its got the latest 500 rows I could set a variable to change the query??

thanks

EDIT:

```
$ts = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['lasttweet']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT tweet_id, tweet_text, screen_name FROM tweets WHERE tweet_id > $ts LIMIT 100") or die (mysql_error());
```

Thsi is what I've tried for the query, but everytime it just gets another 100 old posts, where I need it to get new ones from then on.

Comment: What you tried so far??

Comment: Add a column that indicates the time at which the records were added, keep track of the relevant value for the last record displayed, and then filter for records which have been added since: `WHERE time_added > ? ORDER BY time_added LIMIT 500`.

Comment: But I need the 500 before the latest row. I have tried something similar using LIMIT but can't get it to work. I'm new to php and don;t have a clue what to try sorry. much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to update the records, use the full version of the LIMIT clause.

```
SELECT ... FROM tweets WHERE ... LIMIT 1 500
SELECT ... FROM tweets WHERE ... LIMIT 501 500
SELECT ... FROM tweets WHERE ... LIMIT 1001 500
```

of course, this will mean you need to keep track of which block you last retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

you have to keep a different field like 'tweeted' with default value 0 and once you fetch the 500 records update tweeted field for those records to 1 and modify your select statement as

```
"SELECT tweet_id, tweet_text, screen_name FROM tweets WHERE tweeted != 1 LIMIT 500"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ts = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['lasttweet']);
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
//Query to get number of rows
$numRows = mysql_query("SELECT tweet_id FROM tweets ") or die (mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($numRows);

//Only show last/latest 500 tweets
$tweetLimit = 500;
if($_GET['lasttweet'] == 0){
  if($rows > $tweetLimit){
    $startFrom = $rows - $tweetLimit;
  }
}else{
  $startFrom = 0;
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT tweet_id, tweet_text, screen_name, profile_image_url 
  FROM tweets 
  WHERE tweet_id > $ts 
  ORDER BY tweet_id
  LIMIT $startFrom, $tweetLimit
  ") 
  or die (mysql_error());
```